# Use JavaScript functions in Laravel (PHP) controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I wanted to re-use my javascript code in a Laravel middleware to make a secure authentication from my back-end.

Currently, the js code uses the crypto-js library and it works perfectly fine, so I would like to simply use the JS functions from my Laravel controller.
I tried to use a js code like in this article : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-javascript-from-php/

But it doesn't works, it just echoes the plain text in the front-end.

Here is what I tried in PHP:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class OAuthController extends Controller
{    
   public function testjsfunction() {
      return '<script type="text/javascript">  
         function myFunction(a, b) {
            return a * b;
         }
         // var x = myFunction(11, 10);
      </script>';
   }

   /**
    * my function called from web.php 
    * Route::get('/login', ([\App\Http\Controllers\OAuthController::class, 'getToken']));
    *
   */
   public function getToken($email, $password) 
   {
      $response = $this->testjsfunction();
      return $response;
   }
?>
```

Is it possible or should I just recreate everything with a PHP library ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add content type

Try this

```
    public function getToken($email, $password) 
    {
      return response($this->testjsfunction(), 200, [
                'Content-Type' => 'text/html'
            ]);
    }
```